# Waiting for promise to fulfill in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm working on a project in Node.js that uses user certificates. I need to generate them synchronously, in a blocking manner, but the library I use (pem) has only asynchronous functions (callbacks). I tried multiple ways to tackle the problem, but none of my tries have been successful. My code looks like this:

```js
function KeyObject(CN, serverKey, days = 365) { // key object
  if (typeof CN !== 'string' ||
    typeof days !== 'number' ||
    typeof serverKey !== 'object') {
    throw TypeError;
  }
  this.CN = CN;
  this.days = days;
  const _this = this;

  async function generatePrivate() {
    var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pem.createPrivateKey((err, obj) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        _this.private = obj.key;
        resolve();
      });
    });
    await p;
  }

  async function generateCert(serviceKey) {
    if (typeof serviceKey !== 'object') {
      throw TypeError;
    }
    var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pem.createCertificate({
        commonName: _this.CN,
        days: _this.days,
        serviceKey: serviceKey.private
      }, (err, obj) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        _this.cert = obj.certificate;
        resolve();
      });
    });
    await p;
  }
  // init the keys
  generatePrivate();
  generateCert(serverKey);
}
```

This code goes straight through and doesn't wait for the functions to complete. What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's impossible to make asynchronous stuff work synchronous. `async`/`await` only makes it (much) nicer to write asynchronous programs.

Answer (score 1):

You should just return the `Promise` from each of those functions - no need to `await` or make them `async`.  You also can't have an `async` constructor, perhaps adding an async factory would work.

Comment: Did as you suggested. Function still doesn't block. Any other ideas?

Comment: Promises won't block, in the traditional sense. Every `async` function will return a promise. And every one will have to be `await`ed or `.then()`ed. So you'd still need to do something like `await generatePrivate()` etc in your `KeyObject` function, and then if you have code that needs to wait for `KeyObject` to resolve, you'll either need an `await` or an `.next()` there too.

Comment: So what can I do to ensure my key and certificate get generated before some other function accesses them?